# Всем привет помогите решить задачу. Я не понимаю как одновременно сделать сортировку по дню и по месяцу уже голову сломал

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

5.2.    Вывести список автомобилей, выпущенных во втором квартале и марка заканчивается на ту же букву (либо на ближайшую от нее), что и ваша фамилия (Запрос должен выводить Марку автомобиля и Модель).
SELECT `Marka_avto`, `Model` FROM `avto` WHERE  day (`Data_of_issue`) BETWEEN 11 and 20 and (`Marka_avto`) like 'V%'

Comment: Приведите пример желаемого результата. Пока трудно понять, что вы хотите получить.